# LWC: lightning-record-form is NOT respecting Page Layout

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have created a custom Page Layout for Case Detail and assigned it to a specific profile. In this layout, we have added multiple sections and rearranged the fields as per client requirement.

If we use the Lightning Aura component "force:recordView", then I could see that the component is rendered properly as per the custom layout defined.

`force:recordView  recordId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">`

If we use the Lightning web component "lightning-record-form", then it is NOT respecting the custom layout i.e., no sections, all the fields displayed.

```
<lightning-record-form 
    record-id={recordId} 
    object-api-name="Case" 
    mode="readonly" columns="2" layout-type="Full"
></lightning-record-form>
```

Anyone else facing this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lightning Record Form doesn't yet support sections. It should pull the field list from the profile assignment but it just dumps the whole layout as one big blob of fields.

Comment: Sad! so we have to do custom implementation to match the layout of force:recordView. Thanks.

Comment: Probably. You can fetch layout & section info in LWC via the UI API if that helps.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a try.

Comment: And I do agree it is sad... I complained on the Partner Community already :P

Comment: Can you give me the link of your post in Partner Community?? Is there any commitment from Salesforce to implement this in future or is this intentional?

Comment: https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A000040Sk4Z

Comment: Any good reference examples of fetching layout & section info in a LWC via the UI API? @CharlesT

Comment: No, since the time LWC was introduced to the ecosystem I've not been on any projects that require custom LWC development so I have not spent a great deal of time with it.