# Can we have the standard layout view design for a lightning:recordViewForm?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We have the following available that is either grid or box in recordViewForm

```
<aura:component>
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="My_Contact__c">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <!-- Your lightning:outputField components here -->
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <!-- More lightning:outputField components here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </aura:component>
```

or

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="My_Contact__c">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Email__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

But I would like to build the  layout in my lightning component after I save the record as we have for the standard view page with sections and fields after we save the record from the standard button new.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can somebody provide some pointers please ?

Comment: Why not use [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation) instead?

Comment: Hi Jayant, According to this post, it is not possible to use recordForm but via UI API.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262434/lwc-lightning-record-form-is-not-respecting-page-layouthttps://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262434/lwc-lightning-record-form-is-not-respecting-page-layout

Comment: Don't quite follow why you can't use `lightning:recordForm` here. Also the link you have here is broken.

Comment: I cannot incorporate sections in lightning:recordForm and that's the reason, I cannot use lightning:recordForm.