# How can I display sections in standard lightning-record-edit-form component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, record-type, lightning-recordeditform

I am working on an org where there already are existing and running projects, and several record types for the Case object. 
I am adding a record type, let's name it A.

The component is supposed to replace the New Action for Case.
I managed to fetch the recordtypeID from the standard record type selection page.
When I get it, I then show a lightning-record-edit-form dynamically using this value.
For the record type A, I use a custom form, but for the other record types, I'm using something like this:

```
        <template if:true={recordtypeA}>
         <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-type-id={selectedRecordType}
         onsubmit={handleSubmit}
         onerror={handleError}
         onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                        <lightning-messages>
                        </lightning-messages>
                        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Section 1</h3>
                    <div>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name=“Field 1”>
                        </lightning-input-field>
            // … other fields
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Section 2</h3>
                    <div>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name=“Field X”>
                        </lightning-input-field>
            // … other fields
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" onclick={closeModal}></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Save Record"></lightning-button>
                    </div>   
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </template>
        </template>

        <template if:true={otherrecordtype}>
        <lightning-record-form
            object-api-name="Case"
            record-type-id={selectedRecordType}
            layout-type="Full"
            mode="edit"
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
            onerror={handleError}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess2}
            oncancel={closeModal}>
        </lightning-record-form>
        </template>
```

It works fine, but my problem is that for the other record types, the sections are not shown.
It shows: 
[image: what it is]
Where it should be: 
[image: what it should be]

Is there any way I can show sections using this dynamic method, or do I have to do all the existing record types' record-edit-forms by hand?

Comment: Looks like this is an idea that has been posted:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015A2oQAE

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not work though. The property displaysections is not recognized. 
Maybe this is because the idea concerns an aura component where I'm using a lightning web component?

I actually found my answer here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/262445/66342 

Apparently, lightning-record-form does not support sections yet.

Comment: Aymen, I posted an "Idea", which is a feature request process for Salesforce. The Idea states that this functionality does not exist yet, but if you upvote it and get your org to upvote the "Idea", it could bump up the priority for Salesforce to work on.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't understand that, had never used this system before.
Thank you!